# Change absolute path to relative path VBA

Tags: vba, excel

please how can I change this

`Set historyWb = Workbooks.Open("U:\DB_DATA\HISTORY_LOG.xlsx")`

to relative path ? DB_DATA\HISTORY_LOG.xlsx

I have two files. If I want copy both of this files to different location I need to have both still connected.

Thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is called `get_relative` and it has an optional value which relative to get. If you do not set the value, it is 1. 
Thus the TestMe module would return the following:

```
\DB_DATA\HISTORY_LOG.xlsx
\HISTORY_LOG.xlsx
```

Here comes the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print get_relative("U:\DB_DATA\HISTORY_LOG.xlsx")
    Debug.Print get_relative("U:\DB_DATA\HISTORY_LOG.xlsx", 2)

End Sub


Public Function get_relative(str_path As String, Optional l_number As Long = 1) As String

        Dim str_result      As String
        Dim l_start         As Long
        Dim l_counter       As Long

        For l_counter = 1 To l_number
            l_start = InStr(l_start + 1, str_path, "\")
        Next l_counter

        get_relative = Mid(str_path, InStr(l_start, str_path, "\"))

End Function
```

Comment: I am little bit confused by this code. Its possible to apply this to 
`Sub XFer()
Dim wb As Workbook, NR As Long
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Quotes.xls")
NR = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result Sheet")
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & NR).Value = .Range("B4").Value
  
End With
wb.Close savechanges:=True
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Activeworkbook.FullName` it'll give you the full path of the currently active file.. but wouldn't you know this if you're saving it there anyway?

Comment: I want use this for save some data to different workbook, but need to have this workbooks conected. I found codes for saving data, but not with relative paths.

Comment: @Nataniell Is it because you don't know what drive it is? (ie. "U:\DB_DATA\HISTORY_LOG.xlsx" could be "T:\DB_DATA\HISTORY_LOG.xlsx" on someone else's PC?) If so, you're better to use the drive name than the assigned letter (like "Drive_NAME:\DB_DATA\HISTORY_LOG.xlsx")

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions here:

i) You can use a workbook to generate the path and alter it

```
Dim Path As String
Path = Application.Substitute(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ThisWorkbook.Name, "")
Path = Path & "Subfolder A\"
```

ii) The second is you should be able to use '.' notation ('.' = this folder, '..' = parent folder)

```
Dim Path AS String
Path = ".\Subfolder A\"
Path = "..\..\Subfolder B\"
```